# Calendar for React JS

Tags: fullcalendar, react-big-calendar, hipaa

I am looking to integrate an OPENSOURCE, free calendar/scheduler for a medical practice app, so receiptionist could book appointment (different types) for multiple clinicians. it needs to show multiple views (of different clinicians), integrate with APIs, integrate also with the external calendars (google, outlook, apple), possibly integrate with video etc.
i need to customized the UI and API. i have developers to customize it.

What opensource, free calendar would be the shortest development time and also free?
Full Calendar seems intersting, but on the free version i am not sure how much customization i can do on my own, and i am not ready yet to pay the premium and find it is limited.

Can the React Big Calendar deliver all the features above?

any other calendar to recommend?

expecting some help on calendar module to choose from?
also - can these calendar used in an hipaa compliant environment?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
. As you're new, please also take the [tour] and read [ask], to understand and get the best out of Stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Fullcalendar's Premium edition just adds more features. Not buying it doesn't restrict the amount of customisation you can do on the features already provided in the free version. I think you could do a lot, if not all of your requirements using the free version, but having the premium one might make it better/easier (e.g. using a Resource to represent a clinician, rather than making your own filtering/representation functionality, perhaps, and/or the additional timeline view could be beneficial possibly).

Comment: It depends though what you mean specifically in terms of "customising the UI" - in theory you can do whatever you like with the help of some CSS and/or JS, but equally if you over-customise you can make upgrading more difficult in future. Your requirements 
 in that respect are too vague at this stage for anyone to be completely certain what issus you might encounter. However it can certainly allow you to integrate with any backend APIs you choose - either with built-in features, or if you simply add some of your own code in the right places and integrate with fullCalendar's hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Big Calendar will allow you to do all of these things. In fact I use it for the exact same use case. That said, as with most components, it's just a layout tool, putting data/appointments (known as `events`) on a grid display. It is up to you, as the developer, to define your API, and attach your functionality. Big Calendar is extremely configurable, and does provide a lot "out of the box", but it is still up to the developer to build out their application.